# CKFinder 3: Moving Resized Image to a destination folder

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder 3 intergrated with CKEditor. Now, after resizing an Image and clicking on *Choose Resized*, I want to move/copy the resized image to another folder using javascript. I am able to get upto the following code.

```
    CKFinder.start({
                onInit: function (finder) {
                     finder.on('file:choose:resizedImage', function (event) {
                        var file = event.data.file;
                        var resizedData = file.get('imageResizeData');
                        var resized = file.get('imageResizeData').get('resized');

                        // Need help here to move the resized image to another folder.

                     });
                 }
    });
```

**NOTE**: I am using ASP.NET Connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `command:send` request to send `CopyFiles` request:
https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-request-command_send

Parameters taken by `CopyFiles` can be found here:
https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckfinder3-net/commands.html#command_copyfiles